# Generate non-repeating random numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I want to generates a sequence of unique random number between 100 and 999. I want to make sure that no numbers are generated twice, to ensure that each number is unique. Here is what I came up with. It does not work. When i run it, the screen is just blank. Can anyone help me?

```
products = {}

def random_key(products)

  rand_key = rand(900) + 100

  while products.has_key?(rand_key)

    rand_key = rand(900) + 100

  end

end

puts random_key(products)
```

Comment: Note the requirements for non-repeated numbers.  That said, you really need a shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 16):

```
a = (100..999).to_a.shuffle
```

then every time you need a new id

```
new_id = a.pop
```

This guarantees that numbers are never reused.  Of course, you'll have problems when you run out of elements on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the last statement in your method is the `while` loop, which will not execute if `products` is empty. Hence function returns `nil`.

Try like this:

```
products = {}

def random_key(products)

  rand_key = rand(900) + 100

  while products.has_key?(rand_key)

    rand_key = rand(900) + 100

  end

  rand_key

end

puts random_key(products)
```

Note however, that this has a potential of getting into an infinite loop once all numbers from 100 to 999 are in `products`

Comment: Please upvote if you like it, but I think Marc Talbot's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9458016/402253 is the one worth accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the while expression which is always nil. You should return the number instead:

```
def random_key(products)
  rand_key = rand(900) + 100
  while products.has_key?(rand_key)
    rand_key = rand(900) + 100
  end
  rand_key
end
```

Note that you can remove duplication by placing "while" after key generation:

```
def random_key(products)
  begin
    rand_key = rand(900) + 100
  end while products.has_key?(rand_key)
  rand_key
end
```

And you can omit `begin end` for a single expression

```
def random_key(products)
  rand_key = rand(900) + 100 while products.has_key?(rand_key)
  rand_key
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Marc Talbot answer is great! But put the answer in your context, let's explain a bit,

First, creates the ids.

```rb
ids = (100..999).to_a.shuffle
```

Now, you can avoid the `while`, the method, the `has_key?`, and so on, and just call `ids.pop`

```rb
products[ids.pop] = {}
```

The final code version is:

```rb
ids = (100..999).to_a.shuffle 
products[ids.pop] = {}
```

The result will be:

```
irb(main):023:0> products[ids.pop] = {}
=> {}
irb(main):024:0> products[ids.pop] = {}
=> {}
irb(main):025:0> products[ids.pop] = {}
=> {}
irb(main):026:0> products[ids.pop] = {}
=> {}
irb(main):027:0> products
=> {554=>{}, 968=>{}, 665=>{}, 181=>{}}
```